# Self signed certificate not working on localhost IIS

Tags: windows, ssl, iis

I have am setting up a very simple test site on my localhost under IIS which needs to be accessible locally from https.  IU have followed the steps below:

- In IIS for my local server, I have created a self signed certificate and stored in the "Personal" store
- I have added a https binding for my test site to this new certificate, the hostname is testite and the port 7001
- Added the entry '127.0.0.1   testsite' to hosts file.

When I try to access https://testsite/index.html through the browser, the browser returns the following error:
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Same problem soccurs if I add the port number to the url, i.e: https://testsite:7001/index.html

More informatiom on the error shows the following:

```
This server could not prove that it is testsite; its security certificate is from Muzz2. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

Comment: *"This server could not prove that it is __testsite__; its security certificate is from __Muzz2__."* - this explains the problem you have. You created a certificate for "Muzz2" but then tried to access it as "testsite". But the name in the certificate should reflect the name you access the site.

Comment: @Steffan Ullrich : Muzz2 is my machine name.  When I create a self signed certificate under IIS manager I see no option to create the certificate for anything else.

Comment: Then you better access it as "Muzz2" and not as "testsite".

Comment: @Steffan Ullrich This is a local development machine which will host several sites for testing, each will need it's own self signed SSL.  Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved using Powershell rather than IIS manager to generate the self signed certificate.  ISS always used the machine name rather than the sitename as the common name.

The powershell command I used was as follows:

New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName testsite -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My

After which mmc was used to place the certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities, and the certificated bindings updated in IIS as you you usually would.